# ¹H NMR and MS analysis of products obtained by Claisen condensation reaction between methyl 2‐methylpropanoate and sodium methoxide

Tags: organic-chemistry

> A student attempted to perform the Claisen condensation below and  analyzed their isolated product by <sup>1</sup>H NMR and MS.
> Propose structures for  both the expected Claisen product and the observed product of this  reaction.
> What could the student change to obtain their desired product?
>
> [image: methyl 2‐methylpropanoate with NaOCH3 in CH3OH (heat)]

This question was asking me to predict the product, both expected and observed.

Comment: The premise here is weird. This substrate cannot undergo a Claisen condensation at all. There is _no expected product_. If you don't know why, it will be a good lesson to figure out why that is.

Comment: I understand that it won't undergo a Claisen condensation because there aren't two alpha protons (the structure I got from the proton NMR basically just gives me the reactant so that's probably it) but yah I was just confused what the desired product would be then and what the student should change. Like he should start with a different reactant?

Comment: Consider starting with propionate

Comment: Start with methyl isobutyrate (your starting compound) and methyl propionate (mixed Claisen). React resulting product with methyl iodide/NaOEt. You get desired product.

Comment: @MathewMahindaratne I think that will give a mixed product in ways you don't want, unless you're using a large excess of the isobutyrate.

Answer (score 2):

Looking at your comment, I believe the main source of confusion may be understanding the underlying reason why the Claisen condensation requires the two α protons.

The first one, obviously, is required for the enolate to form. The second one is arguably equally important because it is the removal of this proton in the condensed product that prevents a retro-Claisen. The Claisen condensation is equilibrium driven to the product by that last deprotonation. Under the conditions listed here, you cannot deprotonate the product to generate the "real" product, so a retro-Claisen will quickly take place to provide the original starting material.

The "desired" product is the bis-methylated β-keto ester. You cannot use the conditions for a Claisen, but, as mentioned in comments, alkylation of the unmethylated β-keto ester should work. If you use a strong electrophile, like methyl iodide, you shouldn't need any harsh basic conditions, especially given the fact that a β-keto ester is quite acidic.

Comment: @andselisk The main reason is that I don't have a meta key on this machine, and I don't know the alt codes without looking them up. LaTeX is fast and easy to remember.

Comment: I don't know how it's on macOS, but on Windows and Linux Meta key can be assigned to pretty much any key on the keyboard (or a key sequence). Plus upright Greek is the proper typesetting in this case, not slanted version that MathJax renders. Anyway, this is a minor thing.

Comment: Well, you motivated me to finally bite the bullet and look into it. I've using this: https://github.com/samhocevar/wincompose

Comment: @andselisk I posted this on meta: https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4766/whats-the-best-alternative-to-mathjax-in-titles-and-for-one-off-symbols/4767#4767 Hopefully, it'll be helpful to someone else.